# Steps to make a private file system working on a fresh install?

Tags: 8, files

How can i make my media files stored as private and protected?
The users shoud only have access to that file if they click from the node file link, on nodes they can access to.

On a fresh install,the only destination option is public

[/admin/structure/media/manage/file/fields/media.file.field_media_file/storage](http:///admin/structure/media/manage/file/fields/media.file.field_media_file/storage)

[image]

EDIT :

i have now /admin/config/media/file-system

Chemin du système privé de fichier
C:\xampp\private

i have created a new file media with private storage destination

i have created on the basic page an entity ref field to that media and create a content

the direct file access is not blocked so i consider it is not working
http://localhost/drupal-8.6.7/system/files/2019-05/recherche-dev.pdf

the documentatiion mention on an apache server /docs/8/core/modules/file/overview

> When you specify the private directory in admin/config/media/file-system it will automatically create the sub-directory & create a simple .htaccess file with Deny from all. This stops Apache from serving files from this director

it does not work

Comment: Have a look in settings.php there's an option where you define the private files path. Unless that's set and writable the option won't be shown

Comment: how writable ? the settings was done as such $settings['file_private_path'] = "sites/default/files/private";

Comment: It needs to be the full file path to the folder and not relative to the website. e.g. /var/www/private. It's also got to be outside of the websites folder structure, there's no point trying to create private files if you stick it in /sites/default/files which is accessible to the outside world. Have a read of the comments within settings.php it explains all of this ready

Comment: It's ok to put it in e.g. sites/default/files/private, as long as your web server is protecting that folder. The default .htaccess that Drupal places there has a `deny from all` which is usually sufficient for apache, other web servers will need something specific configured. Outside the docroot is definitely preferable, though, it will help to avoid possible errors from upstream config (e.g. the folder somehow becomes `AllowOverride none` from the web server config, rendering the `deny` in .htaccess useless), and make the site more easily portable to other server software in the future

Comment: what would be the nginx  conf in that case ?